# TeamCity Building separate pull request in a multi VCS setup

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am trying to setup TeamCity 10 for a larger project. We have 3 different GitHub repos which all are needed to build. They can't be build individually as the setup is today. If I set up the project with all of the GitHub repos I can put them all in one folder an successfully build everything.

The structures basically just looks like this:

- Base repo
- UI repo
- Plugins repo

Which all checks out to the same folder and start building.

My problem now is that I need to run build on specific pull request per repo. I need a way to manually or automatically start a build for example PR 1234 on Plugins repo and then use the master on the rest of them.

I've tried several setups but I just can't get it to work as I want to. The best would be if the manual build start popup would have the "branch" drop-down menu for each of the repos but it always just have that one.

I thought about using snapshot dependencies but it seems like that would require each of them to be built individually which currently can't be done. I want them to be "pulled" individually and built as one project.

I appreciate any help on the issue and feel free to ask questions if something is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done to achieve this is creating multiple VCS Configurations and 3 seperated projects.

1. Base Repo : Default branch : master
2. Base Repo : Default branch : master + Branch specifications     `+:/refs/pull/*/merge`
3. UI Repo : Default branch : master
4. UI Repo : Default branch : master + branch specifications `+:/refs/pull/*/merge`
5. Plugin repo : Default branch : master
6. Plugin repo : Default branch : master + branch specification `+:/refs/pull/*/merge`

### Base Repo Pull Requests:

We will build the Pull Request of the Base Repo (2)

This project will build the pull requests using UI Repo on `master` version. (3)

This project will build the pull requests using Plugin repo on `master` version. (5)

### UI Repo Pull Requests:

We will build the pull requests of the UI Repo  (4)

This project will build the pull requests using the base Repo on `master` version. (1)

This project will build the pull requests using plugin repo on `master` version. (5)

### Plugin Pull Requests:

We will build the pull requests of the plugin repo (6)

This project will build the pull requests using the base repo on `master` version. (1)

This project will build the pull requests using the UI Tests on `master` version. (3)

## EDIT:

### How to handle the pull requests

From the comment, I complete this answer.
I created a `watcher` in order to launch automatically the build of the pull request. The `watcher` is a TeamCity Build which run peridoically with the `schedule trigger` feature.

Here is the pseudo code of the feature

```
parameters:
   - ValidatorName

Load Octokit
// Filter is on every Open Pull Request
openPR = Octokit.PullRequest.GetAllForRepository(filter);      

foreach(pr in openPR) {

    // Define if the PR should be queued.
    // Check if the PR is not already queued.
    queuedBuilds = Execute-HttpGetCommand ("http://<teamcityServerUrl>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue?locator=buildType:validatorName");
    foreach(queued in queuedBuilds) {
        if(queued.branchName = pr.Number) {
               # Flag to not queue the build.
               shouldQueue = false;
        }
    }   

    if(shouldQueue) {
        Execute-HttpPostCommand(
            "http://<teamcityServerUrl>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue", 
            "<build branchName=""pr.Number""><buildType id=""validatorName""/><comment><text>Automatic launcher of Pull Request</text></comment></build>");
    }
}
```

The notion of `validator` appear, and it is a special build, with snapshot dependencies of what we would like to test on our pull request.
This build will load octokit and use `Octokit.MergePullRequest` object.

Comment: Sounds like a doable solution! Do you use the built in branch drop-down menu when picking what pull request to use or have you setup something manually with building parameters?

Comment: Edit has been made in order to answer to the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If they can't be built individually then they shouldn't be in separate repos.

If they were all in the the same repo, it will save you alot of problems, and you can then control when to build via pull-request and feature branches.

Comment: Yeah I know it's not a optimal setup and I have sent the proposal to change that but right now it's what we got to work with.

Comment: as a quick fix, maybe add them together via sub-modules? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules